# How integrate jQuery plugin in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, webpack

I want to use https://github.com/t1m0n/air-datepicker with in a React app, but it doesn't work.

```js
import React from 'react';
import AirDatepicker from 'air-datepicker';

class Datepicker extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <AirDatepicker />
    )
  }
}

export default Datepicker;
`
```

```html
<script src="./../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This produces:

```
error($ is not defined)
```

Another approach:

```js
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import AirDatepicker from 'air-datepicker';

class Datepicker extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <AirDatepicker />
    )
  }
}

export default Datepicker;
```

Same error.

How can I integrate a jQuery plugin with React?

Comment: Did you npm install jquery when you tried to import it?

Comment: Follow https://github.com/ryanflorence/react-training/blob/gh-pages/lessons/05-wrapping-dom-libs.md . This question is too broad for stackoverflow.

Comment: https://github.com/ryanflorence/react-training/blob/gh-pages/lessons/05-wrapping-dom-libs.md  is deprecated

Comment: Raymond, yes, i npm installed jquery

Comment: maybe is because i use react-create-app

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First of all `air-datepicker` **is not React component**, it's jQuery plugin, so it won't work like in your examples.

Secondly, for proper work, jQuery should be availabel in global context, the most esiest ways to do this is to include it into page via `<script>` tag. It should be included **before** plugin script.

To check if its really included and it available globally, just type in Chrome console `window.jQuery`and press **Enter** it should return something like `function (a,b){...}`. If not, when you doing something wrong, check `src` attribute of `<script>` tag, maybe it pointing to wrong destination

**How to get it worked in React?**

Well, the most simpliest way is just to initialize plugin on any DOM element in your component, like in regular JavaScript.

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.initDatepicker();
  }
  
  initDatepicker(){
    $(this.refs.datepicker).datepicker();
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Choose date!</h3>
        <input type='text'  ref='datepicker' />
      </div>    
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="app"></div>
```

**As separate component**

Very simple datepicker React component example

```js
class Datepicker extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.initDatepicker();
  }
  
  initDatepicker(){
    $(this.refs.datepicker).datepicker(this.props);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <input type='text' ref='datepicker'/>
    )
  }
}


class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Choose date from React Datepicker!</h3>
        <Datepicker range={true} />
      </div>    
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Also don't forget to include **css** files.

Comment: i got this error after doing it.
TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6___default(...)(...).datepicker is not a function

with create-react-app

Answer (score 3):

`air-datepicker` is not the React-component. It is the jquery-plugin, so we can follow this tutorial https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html

```
import React from 'react'
import $ from 'jquery'
import 'air-datepicker/dist/js/datepicker.js'
import 'air-datepicker/dist/css/datepicker.css'

class AirDatepicker extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        this.$el = $(this.el)
        this.$el.datepicker()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input ref={el => this.el = el}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default AirDatepicker
```

But it still not work cause the `jquery` not the dependency of the `air-datepicker`.

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
./node_modules/air-datepicker/dist/js/datepicker.js
D:/demo/react/jq-plugin/datepicker/node_modules/air-datepicker/dist/js/datepicker.js:2236
  2233 |         }
  2234 |     };
  2235 | })();
> 2236 |  })(window, jQuery);
  2237 | 
  2238 | 
  2239 | //////////////////
```

Follow the error message and the easiest way is to hake the `air-datepicker`. Add `jQuery` as the dependency in the first line of the `air-datepicker/dist/js/datepicker.js`

Before:

```
  1 |;(function (window, $, undefined) { ;(function () {
  2 |    var VERSION = '2.2.3',
  3 |        pluginName = 'datepicker'
```

After:

```
> 1 |import jQuery from 'jquery'
  2 |;(function (window, $, undefined) { ;(function () {
  3 |    var VERSION = '2.2.3',
  4 |        pluginName = 'datepicker'
```

Thus `<AirDatepicker />` can works well as the React-component.

Answer (score 2):

My Solution is

```
import 'stupid-table-plugin';
...


async componentDidMount() {
   window.$("table").stupidtable()
}
```