# Using jquery plugin with React and webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, tablesorter

I work on an older React application that imports [jquery table sorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) for displaying table to user and allowing of sort / filter. I recently migrated this application from gulp to webpack and now on builds I receive an error that '.tablesorter()' is undefined.

Previously, we used tablesorter like:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    let filterOption = false;
    let widgetOption = ["sortTbody"];
    if (this.props.items.length > 1) {
      filterOption = true;
      widgetOption = ["sortTbody", "filter"];
    }
    $("#sortabletable").tablesorter({
      widgets: widgetOption,
      widgetOptions: {
        sortTbody_primaryRow: ".main",
        sortTbody_sortRows: false,
        sortTbody_noSort: "tablesorter-no-sort-tbody",
        scroller_jumpToHeader: false,
        scroller_upAfterSort: false,
        filter_childRows: filterOption
  }
});
```

And made sure to import tablesorter library in our index.html like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/tablesorter-master/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/tablesorter-master/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
<script src="/libs/tablesorter-master/js/widgets/widget-sortTbodies.js">
```

Right now, I dont have time to implement a new table library. How can I go about making this jquery plugin work with modern React? I have read [Integrating with Other Libraries](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html) but I seem to be unable to get a working solution.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to import the `tablesorter` in your js files for webpack to be able to work with it.Here is the npm pckg https://www.npmjs.com/package/tablesorter. Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44731221/how-integrate-jquery-plugin-in-react

Comment: I had previously tried importing tablesorter, which actually allowed the code to compile, but sorting did not work (ironically, filtering did).