# Where to include script of gridester.js in react components?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, gridster, react-grid-layout

I'm simply trying to execute normal gridster.js in react to create some movable and resizable grids. But My problem is I don't know where to add script and how can I import those js files. in their official site the created gridder.js and gridster.js as two different files but how we can include jquery.gridster.js and where it can be placed in my folder? and one more thing is how we can combine that downloaded git with our program? how to write jquery code and where it should be placed?

Please help with this.[[image: This is my App.js][1]]

[[image: gridder.js][2]]

Comment: Hi , Documentation clearly says it should go in head section of the your app, just navigate to your html and add it as any other jquery plugin and it should work? https://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/

Comment: In which head tag? Index.html in public folder? then I have to create two js files seperately? like gridder and gridster?

Comment: you can try answer form this post , it talks how to integrate jquery plugins with react https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44731221/how-integrate-jquery-plugin-in-react